# How to choose appropriate parameter vector for linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model, predictor

If we have a dataset $D := f(x_i, y_i)^n_{i=1}$ where $x_i = [x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}, ... , x_{i_p}]^T$ is a p-dimensional
predictor and $y_i \in R$ is the response to $x_i$.

Now, shall we select as our parameter vector   $\beta = [\beta_1,  ... , \beta_p]$ and choose our model to
be $\hat{y}_i =  \beta^Tx_i$
or select as our parameter vector $\beta^{'}_i = [1, \beta_{i_1}, , ... ,\beta_{i_p}]$ and choose our model to be $\hat{y}_i =  \beta^{'T}x^{'}_i$ where $x^{'}_i = [1, x_{i_1}, ... ,x_{i_p}]^T$.

I think that padding 1 at the first element of $\beta$ vector is wrong, this will make the bias term 1 all the time which should not be the case.